# 'WebHost' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ocelot

I am trying to follow Microsoft's Ocelot API Gateway tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/implement-api-gateways-with-ocelot).

First I intialized a new empty ASP.NET Core web app:

```
dotnet new web
```

Then I installed the Ocelot dependencies (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ocelot/):

```
dotnet add package Ocelot --version 17.0.0
```

Then I took the code from the tutorial:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Ocelot.DependencyInjection;
using Ocelot.Middleware;
using System.IO;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);

            builder.ConfigureServices(s => s.AddSingleton(builder))
                    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(
                          ic => ic.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine("configuration",
                                                            "configuration.json")))
                    .UseStartup<Startup>();
            var host = builder.Build();
            return host;
        }
    }
}
```

But then it complains that the WebHost class, called in BuildWebHost method, "is inaccessible due to its protection level". According to Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webhost), WebHost "provides convenience methods for creating instances of IWebHost and IWebHostBuilder with pre-configured defaults.", and looks like so:

```
public static class WebHost
...
```

Why does it complain that WebHost is inaccessible, when the class is in fact public? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webhost?view=aspnetcore-5.0), `WebHost` is in the namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore`. But in your code, It hasn't the using to this namespace.

In Visual Studio, you can try **Go to definition** on `WebHost` to discover where the type come.

As sujested by @leiflundgren, as your code has the using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting`, then the compiler thinks you want use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost`.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/WebHost.cs

```cs
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

internal sealed partial class WebHost : IWebHost, IAsyncDisposable
{
....
}
```

But this class has the scope `internal`, then it isn't exposed and can be used by your code. Hence the following error :

> WebHost is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: There is another `WebHost` class in namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` which the compiler thinks this is a reference to.

Comment: @leiflundgren, In [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting), I see IWebHost and WebHostDefault, but no class `WebHost`.

Comment: I am using netcore 6, Assembly `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting`, Version=6.0.0.0 has a `WebHost`

Comment: @leiflundgren, thank. I add this information in my answer.